# Add new well-known symbol property like Symbol.myProperty in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, symbols

In JavaScript we have global symbol on the `Symbol` object, such as [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) and [`Symbol.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/match).

I can assign the property by erasing the type to `any`, however TypeScript doesn’t recognise it.

```
// Define Symbol.hello
(Symbol as any).hello = Symbol("hello");

// Try using it later:
Symbol.hello;
// TypeScript error: Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.ts(2339)
```

How do I add my property to `Symbol` in a way that makes TypeScript happy?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have added “How do I add my property to Symbol in a way that makes TypeScript happy?”. Does that explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your property on the `SymbolConstructor` interface:

```
declare global {
  interface SymbolConstructor {
      readonly hello: symbol;
  }
}
```

You can now define your property:

```
// Define Symbol.hello
(Symbol as { hello: symbol }).hello = Symbol("hello");

// TypeScript is now happy:
Symbol.hello;
```